# r language mtext not working with image.plot array

Tags: r

I am using R to plot an array of plots using image.plot. Everything works well except that I cannot get mtext() to display a main title. Using very similar code for an array of plots using matplot() works fine.

The code I am using is given below.

```
op <- par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
par(oma = c(0,0,2,1))
for (i in 2:nout){
  image.plot(r,th,t(u[i,,]),xlab="r",ylab=expression(paste(theta)),
    zlim=c(0.1,0.9), main=paste("t = ",t[i]),col=pal)
} 
mtext(side=3, outer=TRUE, cex=1.25, line=2,expression(
  paste("u(t,r,",theta, ")")))
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you get an error? Or how is the result you get wrong?

Answer (score 11):

I've run into some weird `mtext()` issues with `image.plot()` as well.  One work around I've found is to use `title()` to "re-engage" the plot device, such that:

`image.plot(x,y,z)

title("")

mtext("Title",side=3)`

Answer (score 0):

You set top outer margin to be 2 lines wide, and you try to print the text on the *third* line, because `line` parameter from `mtext` starts at `0`:

> line: on which MARgin line, starting at 0 counting outwards.

Comment: I have tried changing code to: `par(oma = c(0,0,4,1))` but still no title

Answer (score 0):

This is a dirty hack, but it works for me at least.

```
plot(0,0, type='n', xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab='', ylab='', bty='n')  # make an empty plot
mtext("Whatever you want in the margin", side=mySide)
par(new=T)
image.plot(…)   # fill in your image plot here
```